# Find the Nth root in R

Tags: r, radix, exponential

How do we find the Nth root in R?

```
4^2 = sqrt(16)
```

But what is the code snippet for the opposite transformation of;

```
4^7 = ???
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple

```r
sqrt(4) == 4^(1/2)
# 7th root of 4
4^(1/7)
```

> In calculus, roots are treated as special cases of exponentiation, where the exponent is a fraction:
>
> [image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#Definition_and_notation

Answer (score 1):

You should probably NOT use x^(1/n). It works perfectly well with nonnegative numbers, but if you tried

```
(-4)^(1/7)
```

you would get `NaN`. A better way is with `nthroot`.

```
> library(pracma)
> nthroot(-4, 7)
[1] 1.219
```